# How can I buffer my data which are read one by one byte and send them as a sequence?

Tags: c

I have a GPS module and I can read only one byte at a time from the i2c bus so I am using a loop similar to this (this is an example code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    char test[26];
    char sendbuf[40];
    for (i=0;i<26;i++) 
    {
        test[i]=i;
    }
}
```

I want to send these data all together and not byte to byte.
Is there any way to put them in a buffer and then send them all at once like:

```
sprintf(sendbuf, "%s", test);
```

**without the use of for(;;)**?

Comment: What is the problem with using `sprintf(sendbuf, "%s", test);`?

Comment: When you ask "without the use of `for`", are you including the one you are using to populate `test`? Is there a problem with sending `test` directly?

Comment: @alk The data may not be '\0'-terminated.

Comment: @timrau: How come you know this? However referring the OP's code it's "garbage-terimnate" in any case, as `sendbuf` if larger then `26`.

Comment: "*I want to send these data ...*" How?

Comment: @alk Well, there may be some other mechanism to indicate the data chunk size.

Comment: I receive these data from a sensor to my raspberryPi in the way i described before.Then i want to send them via a UDP socket to my computer with Ethernet port. The problem is that i must define the buffer from which i will send these data. So i need to buffering them. I 've tried sprintf and memcpy also...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy()`.

```
memcpy(sendbuf, test, sizeof(test));
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Yes, and here it's definitely misleading, because `sizeof test` already yields the size of `test` _in `char`s_ (not the number of elements).

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void main()
{

int i;
char buffer[20];
char cmd[20];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sprintf(buffer+i, "%d", i);
}
sprintf(cmd,"%s",buffer);
printf("%s", cmd);


printf("\n");
}
```